# Java library: using JPMS to prevent internal library classes from using them

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

I'm trying to separate public API from internals in a library, so that users of that library can not instantiate internal classes.

As I understand, normally this is achieved through making internal things private/package protected. But this library is already written and it would be a lot of effort to refactor it in that way.

After some reading I've found out about the java modules, and that we can explicitly say which packages we would like to expose. So I did it in that way:

- moved API classes to *.api package and internal to *.internal
- created a Java module like this:

```java
module some.library{
    exports some.library.api;
    requires etc1;
}
```

After that I've compiled my library and used it in another project

```xml
<parent>
    <artifactId>some.library</artifactId>
    <groupId>some.library</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

And after that I've tried to instantiate some classes from *.internal package and it's still working (I can access these internal classes from the other project).

So the main question - could modules used for something like this or is it used only to specifying new abstraction levels in-between packages in the same application?

Comment: Yes, this is one of the primary use cases of modules, and even when you use private and package protected, Reflection could get around that... but not with modules.

Comment: Your "it's still working" comment is unclear.  You should still be able to use the internal classes from inside your library but not from the other class.  Is that what you saw?

Comment: @DanielWiddis no, I meant that I'm able to use the internal classes from other classes (outside my library) and exactly this I'm trying to prevent

Comment: That shouldn't be possible *IF* the other project is modular.   If the other project doesn't have a module descriptor it access your project the old way.

Comment: @DanielWiddis thank you! It's good to know. 
How do you think, if there is some another way to achieve that rather then put all internals in private/package protected in library?

Comment: Generally no way to “enforce” it that’s not heavyweight.  You can use custom class annotations to communicate to users what they “should” not extend or used some sort of mechanism to mine the stack trace to inspect the calling class…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the main question - could modules used for something like this or is it used only to specifying new abstraction levels in-between packages in the same application?

Yes, modules can be used for this, and in fact were one of the primary motivators for Project Jigsaw (which became JPMS).

[JSR-376](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Emr/jigsaw/spec/), which defines the JPMS specification, includes strong encapsulation as one of its two fundamental capabilities:

> This specification achieves that goal by providing two fundamental capabilities:
>
> *Reliable configuration*, to replace the brittle, error-prone class-path mechanism with a means for program components to declare explicit dependences upon one another, along with
>
> *Strong encapsulation*, to allow a component to declare which of its public types are accessible to other components, and which are not.

[JEP-260](https://openjdk.org/jeps/260), part of the implementation, explicitly does this behavior for the JDK itself:

> **Summary**
>
> Encapsulate most of the JDK's internal APIs by default so that they are inaccessible at compile time, and prepare for a future release in which they will be inaccessible at run time.

This all seems like a good idea and would have been had it been included in the language specifications from the beginning.  However, using modules is still somewhat opt-in because Java also loves to support backwards compatibility and doesn't want to break a huge existing ecosystem where developers say things like:

> this library is already written and it would be a lot of effort to refactor it in that way.

To support backwards compatibility, Java separated the *module path* (which enforces this encapsulation) from the *class path* (the old way of doing things).  The class path fits into the module system as an "unnamed module".

So if consumers of a library don't use modules, those imported classes end up on the class path, and they can do everything they used to be able to do, including accessing any package they want, and even working around access modifiers like `private` by (ab)using reflection (which simply requires a JVM argument to enable).   Many large java libraries still rely on reflection to do their work (e.g., JNA, Spring Boot, Jackson).

> And after that I've tried to instantiate some classes from *.internal package and it's still working.

Without forcing other libraries to be modular to use your libraries, there's not much you can do to explicitly prevent it.  However, if you're willing to accept "you shouldn't" rather than "you can't" then there are many options available to you.  Some simpler ones:

- Move classes into a package with a clear indication of its usage in its name (*.internal) as you have done.
- Without moving any classes, use an annotation on the class such as `@foobar.api` and `@foobar.internal` to clearly communicate to users what they are supposed to use.

In parallel with this, motivate users to comply with this behavior by respecting [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) for your API classes, but not requiring it (and even warning users) that internal class APIs may change (frequently) which will discourage users from taking dependencies on them.

Comment: thank you! this fully answered my question